# convert between str of text and lists of numbers in which described in the Numerical Equivalents of Letters

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

dic is a lookup dic for letters to number and numdic is a lookup for num to letters

```
    'k':'10','l':'11','m':'12','n':'13','o':'14','p':'15','q':'16','r':'17','s':"18",'t':'19','u':'20',
    'v':'21','w':'22','x':'23','y':'24','z':'25'}
numdic = {'0':'a','1':'b','2':'c','3':'d','4':'e','5':'f','6':'g','7':'h','8':'i',
    '9':'j','10':'k','11':'l','12':'m','13':'n','14':'o','15':'p','16':'q','17':'r','18':'s','19':'t','20':'u',
    '21':'v','22':'w','23':'x','24':'y','25':'z'}

def encode(message):
    cipher = ''
    for letter in message:
        # checks for space
        if(letter != ' '):
            #adds the corresponding letter from the lookup_table
            cipher += dic[letter]
        else:
            # adds space
            cipher += ' '

    return cipher

def decode(nummessage):
    ciphertext = ''
    for letter in nummessage:
        if (letter != ' '):
            ciphertext += numdic[letter]
        else:
            ciphertext  +=' '
    return ciphertext

# Driver function to run the program
def main():
    #encrypt the given message
    print('Enter a message to encrypt:')
    message = input()
    print(encode(message))
    print('Enter message to decrypt:')
    nummessage = input()
    #decrypt the given message
    print(decode(nummessage))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when i run the code, for decoding if i enter 18 for example it gives me bi instead of s, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are interpreting `18` as `'18'`. Then, when you iterate over that you get `'1'` and `'8'`. Try:

```
def decode(nummessage):
    ciphertext = ''
    for letter in nummessage.split(','):
        if (letter != ' '):
            ciphertext += numdic[letter]
        else:
            ciphertext  +=' '
    return ciphertext
```

And you can use it like this:

```
>>> decode("18,1,2")
sbc
```